# Insert formula to sum from current and last worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook where I need to be creating new sheets in which I need to change the formula of cells from I8 to I39 to be the sum of H8 and I8 of the previous sheet. So in sheet3  I8 value must be `=H8+sheet2!I8`.

```
Dim aCell As String
Dim bCell As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 8 To 39

aCell = Cells(i, 7).Address
bCell = Cells(i, 8).Address '<--need this but on the previus sheet

Cells(i, 9).Formula = "= & aCell & "+" & bCell"  '<--i need the formula to be "=i,8+i,8(previus sheet)

Next i
```

This was as far as I could get, you can see what I was trying to do but I don't know the syntax.

Comment: you can do the whole thing with one line using formulaR1C1. `ActiveSheet.Range("I8:I39").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC-1 + Sheet2!RC"`.  This will place the correct formula.  Change Sheet2 to the name of the sheet you want.  FormulaR1C1 uses a relative address.  So it uses the cell into which the formula is being placed then moves based on the number following to know where and how far away the desired cell address is. R1C10 moves down one row and right ten columns.

Comment: like i said i need to create new sheets all the time, i cant fix the Sheet2 name. It must be the reference the previus Sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrowing a bit from Scott Craner's comment:

```
Dim PrevSheet As Integer

PrevSheet = Application.ActiveSheet.Index - 1
ActiveSheet.Range("I8:I39").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC-1 + " & Sheets(PrevSheet).Name & "!RC"
```

This works as long as you have the correct sheet selected, and the indexes of the sheets are defaults, that is Sheet1 is indexed 1, Sheet2 is indexed 2.
If you add or delete sheets, this might not always be the case.

Comment: If you are going to go this far just set the worksheet variable, then in the formula to the worksheet.name.

Comment: i used your code, se second part seens to be working but the RC-1 its not... heres what i get [    =I9-1 + '2'!I9    ]  .. is the syntax correct?

Comment: Fixed it  used [        ActiveSheet.Range("I8:I39").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]" & " + " & Sheets(PrevSheet).Name & "!RC"      ]   . Thanks alot, you just saved me lots and lots of hours in my job.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to rely on the current [Worksheet.Index property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836415.aspx) to retrieve the name of the previous sheet. The [Range.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) can supply the rest.

```
Sub newFormulas()
    Dim i As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet3")
        For i = 8 To 39
            .Cells(i, 9).Formula = _
                Chr(61) & .Cells(i, 8).Address(0, 0) & Chr(43) & _
                Worksheets(.Index - 1).Range(.Cells(i, 9).Address).Address(0, 0, external:=True)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

I've used soe ASCII codes with the [Chr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613dxh46(v=vs.90).aspx) to avoid having to deal with a lot of quoted string parts.

Comment: i couldn't use your code, but thanks alot for taking your time to answer. I dont know enough to make it work or understand what i'm doing wrong.